# undefined method `refreshProfile_affinity_path' for #<#<Class:0x8daee70>:0x8dbdc30>

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, updates, put, undefined-function

I'm getting the error in the title. I am not sure how exactly to write the routes, controller, and index.

I am trying to create a 'Refresh' button in an `index.html.erb` view shown below:

```
...
<td><%= link_to 'Refresh', refreshProfile_affinity_path(a), method: :put %></td>
...
```

It is using this route in `routes.rb`:

```
  resources :affinities
  put 'affinities/refreshProfile/:id' => 'affinities#refreshProfile'
```

It is trying to access the following method in the `affinities_controller.erb`:

```
...
def refreshProfile
    @affinity = Affinity.find(params[:id])
    new_profile_affinity = User.find(@affinity.user_A_id).profile_affinity_with(User.find(@affinity.user_B_id))

    if @affinity.update_attributes(:integer, new_profile_affinity)
        redirect_to @affinity
    end
end
...
```

What could be wrong? Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add an `as:` to your route, this is what specifies the prefix for the helper method and is why you're currently getting an undefined method error e.g.

```
put 'affinities/refreshProfile/:id' => 'affinities#refreshProfile',
  as: 'refreshProfile_affinity'
```

`refreshProfile_affinity_path` would then work, or you could give it a shorter, snappier name e.g. `as: 'refreshProfile'` and then use `refreshProfile_path`.

Comment: That did it! What exactly does `as:` do? Thanks again!

Comment: It's used to specify the name used to generate the routing helper methods. If you run `rake routes` from the command line you'll see all the routes for your app. The restful routes get helper methods by default e.g. `affinity_path` but if you add a custom route using `put...` you need to specify what the prefix for the helper functions will be for that route. Hope that helps!